# Адаптер на JAVA для разных версий программы

Tags: java, архитектура, adapter

Всем привет!

**Есть следующая задача:** необходимо разработать адаптер для программы. Для этого разработчик программы предоставляет два файла с API (api1.jar, api2.jar), которые, собственно, и следует адаптировать.

**Проблема** заключается в том, что адаптер должен поддерживать одновременно несколько версий программы (Например, версии 9 и 10. Либо только 10). Соостветственно для каждой версии свои api1.jar, api2.jar.

Отсюда и возникают **следующие вопросы**:

1) Как должна выглядеть структура/архитектура адаптера?

2) Как сделать так, чтобы при вызове конкретной версии использовались правильные API файлы?

Возможно уже есть готовые решения данной проблемы.

Comment: зависит от специфики. Легче всего реализовать отдельные веб-сервисы -- адаптеры для конкретных версии API (скажем, для 9-й версии -- свой сервис, для 10-й -- свой). В дальнейшем делать к ним веб-запросы, исходя из версии. Но микросервисная архитектура имеет свои недостатки. Обертку под веб можно попытаться обобщить, переиспользовать. При появлении новой версии нужно будет лишь сделать адаптер для нее, добавить веб-обертку, и включить её в план маршрутизации запросов.

Comment: насколько помню, в java нельзя использовать разные версии одной билиотеки из-за конфликта имён классов. Поэтому 2-я проблема решается, на мой взгляд, лишь через сервисы (не обязательно веб-сервисы)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Спасибо за ответ. В описании забыл указать, что речь идет о десктопном приложении.

Comment: не думаю, что это что-то меняет. Десктопное приложение также может быть клиентом сервера, как и серверное приложение. Хотя есть нюансы

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, мне уже доводилось реализовывать нечто подобное при разработке адаптера  для приложения, основывающегося на Eclipse. Там это решалось благодаря разбиению  адаптера на плагины для каждой версии, OSGI технологии и активатору, в котором и решалось, какой plugin для какой версии следует использовать. Здесь же следует реализовать подобное, но без Eclipse и OSGI. Чтобы не изобретать велосипед и был задан этот вопрос. Вряд ли я первый, кто с таким столкнулся...

Answer (score 1):

В итоге ответ нашелся на Хабре. Вопрос решался использованием модулей. Вот [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/339026/).

Comment: Хорошо бы основное из статьи в ответ перенести.

Comment: Интересно. Т.е. можно написать свой загрузчик классов для разных модулей, и тем самым обойти проблему с конфликтом имен классов у разных версий. Спасибо! Хотя вопрос скорее всего не удовлетворяет критерию StackOverflow: вопрос должен быть таким, чтоб предполагаемый ответ умещался в 2-3 абзаца (а не в статью или в книгу). В принципе, ответ тоже не удовлетворяет, но на мой взгляд, полезен.